# How would one go about sizing hardware and disk space for a nagios server installation?

Tags: nagios, sizing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

We need to configure a nagios installation to monitor our infrastructure. As in any project, the first step is figuring out the hardware and storage requirements, so that we can install it on appropriate equipment. Unfortunately, I have been unable to find any estimates of any of these needs--only the statement:

> The only requirement of running Nagios Core is a machine running Linux (or UNIX variant) that has network access and a C compiler installed (if installing from source code).

While that is easy enough to accomplish, there is no reference to required disk space, database loading, process loads, etc.

Are there any useful guides or calculators (spreadsheets?) that folks are using to size their installations?

*EDIT*

A little more info:

- This will probably be deployed as a VM, so disk space requirements are important
- We'll want to use MySQL on a different host as a data store

Comment: Anecdotally, at $LastJob I ran Nagios on an old PowerEdge 1850 with 2GB RAM, 2x 73GB 10K SCSI disks in RAID 1, and a dual core Xeon on CentOS 5 with no problem. This monitored about 60 servers and didn't break a sweat. In a vanilla nagios install there is no database, it's all flat config files.

Comment: Thanks; it seems processing load won't be much of an issue, but we're most likely going to be setting up a VM for this, which means that the disk space is dear. We have a DB server that we'll configure as the data store, but knowing the usage there will also be a factor.

Comment: @MDMarra - agreed. In my experience, Nagios is **extremely** lightweight. At a past job, our Nagios system ran on a very meager 1GB RAM, 1 CPU ESXi VM. It checked somewhere in the neighborhood of 50-75 network switches, a handful of routers, ~200 wireless access points, and around 130 servers, each of which had anywhere from 5-20 services monitored.

Comment: @BryanAgee - only you can answer your question about log storage. By default, Nagios logs to flat text files, which get compressed and rotated automatically. Obviously if you're logging to a database, you'll need to homebrew some sort of export/purging method to expire old data.